# что такое и для чего нужен ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: php, .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

что такое и для чего нужен ASP.NET Web API? Можно ли на нем написать WEB API-REST (php) для сервера который на веб хостинге?

Answer (score 2):

В какой-то момент в WebMatrix была поддержка PHP, но насколько я помню использовать его можно было только как вариант разметки в шаблонах собственно страниц. В бэкенде, насколько я помню использовать PHP в ASP.NET нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Рест сервисы на нём писать можно и нужно, он для этого и предназначен, но язык тут не php а .NET совместимые языки в основном это C#.

Но последняя версия .NET на данный момент - ASP.NET Core 2.0. А Web API это более старый вариант.